# Change/decrease point size in GGally and ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

The points in ggpairs are way too big. How do I make them smaller?

Comment: do you have an example code or line ?

Comment: The help page for `?ggpairs` gives several examples of how to refine the plots

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This basically requires reading the help page and working through the examples. Turns out that there are (at least) two different sets of attributes that might affect point size. Below you will see the two that I found.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(GGally)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1], 200), ]

# Custom Example  ( almost directly from help page)
pm <- ggpairs(
 diamonds.samp[, 1:5],
 mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),
 upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), combo = "box"),
 lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3,    size=0.1), 
              combo = wrap("dot", alpha = 0.4,            size=0.2) ),
 title = "Diamonds"
)
 pm
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in ggpairs(dt[1:2000, 26:32], mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),  : 
  could not find function "wrap"

Comment: Since `wrap` is part of package:GGally, I'm unable to explain. Are your versions of R and GGally current? I just tested again with GGally_1.2.0 in R 3.2.3.

Comment: ´mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut)´ have the ´cut´parameter form diamond dataset. Replace the word "cut" for your variable name